# Modify alpha opacity of LESS variable

Tags: css, variables, less, opacity, alpha

Using LESS, I know that I can change the saturation or tint of a color variable. That looks like this:

```
background: lighten(@blue, 20%);
```

I want to change the alpha opacity of my color, though. Preferably like this:

```
background: alpha(@blue, 20%);
```

Is there a simple way to do this in LESS?

Answer (score 329, accepted):

The [site documentation](http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-operations-fade) gives the answer:

```
background: fade(@blue, 20%);
```

The function name is `fade` not `alpha` according to that document.

Comment: Thanks! I've been getting tired of converting everything to RGBA!

Comment: I was looking for the darken and lighten .. Docs got me there. Thanks

Comment: I agree 'fade' doesn't seem accurate to me. Sass does it right: alpha(), opacity(), and rgba().

Comment: For the record, `fade()` doesn't work with CSS vars -- i.e. `fade(var(--mycolor), 20%)`

Answer (score 36):

### For completeness

**fade**

Set the absolute transparency of a color. Can be applied to colors
whether they already have an opacity value or not.

```
background: fade(@blue, 20%);
```

**fadein**

Decrease the transparency (or increase the opacity) of a color, making
it more opaque.

```
background: fadein(@blue, 80%);
```

**fadeout**

Increase the transparency (or decrease the opacity) of a color, making
it less opaque. To fade in the other direction use fadein.

```
background: fadeout(@blue, 20%);
```

[View Complete Documentation](http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-operations-fade)

Comment: Fadeout is exactly what I was looking for, thank you !